# Replacement or comparable model for my current Bottom Bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

I am currently using a old mountain bike which is using a Shimano BB -LP26 / 68 x110 Size: BC 1.37x24 
I am not sure if this model is with english treading or Italian treading. I understand the don't make this type of BB anymore.

Can someone help me or give me some idea to what other Shimano models can I use for this old bike.I am bringing my old MTB back to life. The frames are in excellent condition.

I need all the help I can. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any square-taper BB with the same spindle length will work. Doesn't even have to be Shimano.

[1.37" x 24tpi is English,](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html) like almost all mountain bikes. (If it is Italian, it'll be immediately obvious when you try to install it - the shell diameter is a couple mm greater.)